# Testing simple React component using Jest and enzyme - what did I wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I'm 'unit testing' greenhorn. What did I wrong here? How can I test such simple components?

`test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import StartButton from './';

describe('StartButton', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<StartButton />);

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.StartButton-container')).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

`startButton`

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import './style.css';

const StartButton = () => (
  <div className="StartButton-container">
    <RaisedButton
      label="Start Here"
      className="StartButton-main-button"
      //onClick={this.addBeer}
    />
  </div>
);

export default StartButton;
```

`error`

> FAIL  src\components\StartButton\test.js   ● StartButton › renders
>   correctly
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
>
>   at Object.it (src/components/StartButton/test.js:13:54)
>       at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>   at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
>       at <anonymous>
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
> ```
>
> PASS  src\components\App\test.js
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total Tests:       1 failed, 2
>   passed, 3 total Snapshots:   2 passed, 2 total Time:        0.181s,
>   estimated 1s Ran all test suites related to changed files.
>
> Watch Usage: Press w to show more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make that kind of assertions you need to use `chai`

```
$ npm install chai
```

**test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import StartButton from './StartButton'

describe('<Foo />', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.StartButton-container')).to.have.length(1);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jest has that matcher syntax built in. You would have to do this:

`expect(wrapper.find('.StartButton-container').length).toBe(1);`

By putting the value you want to check inside the `expect()`.